# How to add ``acknowledgements'' on documentclass ``memoir''?

Tags: sectioning, acknowledgements

I am using

`\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}`

for a writing a paper, and would like to add

`acknowledgements`.

But I can't do this. My plan is to put this after

`abstract`

and before the

`contents`.

Please help!

Comment: if the paper isn't going to be submitted as a source file to a publisher who applies automated procedures to extract portions (in particular, the abstract) for other uses, you could include the acknowledgments as part of the abstract, mimicking the style of the abstract header to start off the acknowledgments.

Comment: is there also a way to add acknowledgements independent of abstract?

Comment: @monomorphic: Did you assure yourself that the publisher does not have a class of its own for this purpose? Will they allow `memoir` at all?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, Sorry I don't understand you. Could you rephrase your question differently?

Comment: @monomorphic: Most publishers of papers have a separate LaTeX class for their journals etc. You should first check if there is such a class provided by your designed publisher. I am not sure they will accept a manuscript written in memoir. By the way, why is this question tagged as `sharelatex`? And there is nothing special for `acknowledgement` actually. A `\section*{}` etc should do

Comment: No, I am not willing to submit for publication yet. I need to create only a PDF and send it to somebody. I am writing the paper in sharelatex.com

Comment: @monomorphic: I am pretty sure a possible answer has nothing sharelatex - specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just uses a `\section*{\ackname}` command to insert a heading and an `itemize` list into the document. Since there is no real information on formatting requirements, I kept it simple. (I would not use it this way, of course, let alone the names ;-))

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{memoir}


\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\ackname}{Acknowledgements}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
\blindtext
\end{abstract}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\section*{\ackname}

I would like to thank

\begin{itemize}
\item Monty Python
\item Sauron
\item Gandalf
\item Frodo
\item Samwise
\item Darth Vader
\end{itemize}

\clearpage % For letting the acknowledgements appear on a separate page


\tableofcontents


\chapter{First really, really important stuff}
\section{Real important stuff}
\subsection{Not that important stuff}

\end{document}
```

[image]